# Nativescript: Continue code execution when app goes to background

Tags: ios, angular, nativescript

(edited to provide updated info)

I have a nativescript app that performs various tasks that I would like to continue going if the phone goes into background mode or is locked.

Focused on iOS, with Nativescript Angular. I am also new to using obj C code in Nativescript.

As an easy example, let's say I want to print to the console every 5 seconds after a user hits a button, so I have the following code in my component ts file:

coolComponent.ts:

```
@Component({...})

Export class coolComponent {
...
whenButtonClicked(){
   setInterval(function(){ 
    console.log('button has been clicked. show every 5 seconds!'); 
  }, 5000);
}
```

Without further code, when the user hits the button, it will print to console every 5 seconds, but then stop when the app is in the background or phone is locked. How do I get the function to continue executing even when app is in the background or locked?

In seeing different sources, like [here (NS docs on background execution)](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/ios-runtime/how-to/BackgroundExecution) and [here (docs on app delegate)](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/application-lifecycle#ios-uiapplicationdelegate) , it looks like the first step is to create a custom-app-delegate, get that to work, and then identify the background task in info.plist.

I have gotten things generally to be functional, like this:

app/custom-app-delegate.ts:

```
import { ios, run as applicationRun } from "tns-core-modules/application";

export class CustomAppDelegate extends UIResponder implements 
    UIApplicationDelegate {

     public static ObjCProtocols = [UIApplicationDelegate];

     public applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
      console.log('in background mode!')
     }
}
```

main.ts:

```
import { platformNativeScriptDynamic } from "nativescript-angular/platform";   

import { AppModule } from "./app.module";

import * as application from "tns-core-modules/application";

import { CustomAppDelegate } from "./custom-app-delegate";

application.ios.delegate = CustomAppDelegate;

platformNativeScriptDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

app/app.module.ts:

```
import { CustomAppDelegate } from "./custom-app-delegate";
```

app/App_Resources/iOS/info.plist:

```
 ...
 <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
  <array>
    <string>fetch</string>
  </array>
```

edit: create reference.d.ts:

```
/// <reference path="./node_modules/tns-platform-declarations/ios.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="./node_modules/tns-platform-declarations/android.d.ts" />
```

Edit: FYI, to get the custom-app-delegate to work, I also had to download "tns-platform-declerations", with the command:

```
$ npm i tns-platform-declarations --save-dev
```

With this, the app properly reads "in background mode!" when the app goes to the background. So the custom-app-delegate is functional.

However, the examples online assume that the code in the custom-app-delegate is independent of the rest of the app, so they assume there are new tasks to do when the app goes into background mode.

That is not the case here. I have a task that is being performed from the coolComponent function, and when the app goes into background or is locked I want that to **continue**.

This probably requires that coolComponent.ts communicate with custom-app-delegate, but I don't know how to do this.

Just repeating the code in both files--having the setInterval function appear in both coolComponent.ts and custom-app-delegate--does not work, because this would not result in the custom-app-delegate continuing on the same timing that began in coolComponent.ts after the user hit the button.

So how can I have the code start in coolComponent.ts and **continue** after the app is in background mode?

Comment: HI, I have the same issue, did you find the solution for this? If you did, then can you please let me know how to handle it.

Comment: I did not figure out how to perform background tasks with app delegate. What I did instead was try to find other solutions (where other folks had figured it out). For example, I used the nativescript local notifications plugin to schedule and then show the user notifications, even if the app is in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can't force your app to be active when user no longer wants it to be (by locking the phone / minimising the app). If you like to run anything in background, you will have to use [background fetch](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/ios-runtime/how-to/BackgroundExecution) in iOS.

Comment: This is not a "user doesn't want app to be active" situation. The idea is that the app can run even if user puts it in their pocket (and they lock it to avoid hitting buttons accidentally). The iphone's basic apps have this functionality: maps, music, clock, and podcasts work this way.  "Fetch" would be the right way to do it for, say, a countdown timer that is running in the background?

Comment: There are different types of background modes, including one for location, fetching data etc., You are supposed to pick the one that suits your requirement. But at high level this is the idea, you can't keep your normal app code running once it's sent to background.

Comment: I have been looking into background execution. I have added the fetch background mode to info.plist, but it also seems like to get that to work, you first need to add a custom-app-delegate, and get that to work through things like installing tns-platform-declarations. I have done that, and been able to get the custom-app-delegate to be functional--it can register when the app goes into background mode. But...

Comment: How do I "continue" the code I have in my main.ts file once the app goes into background? The examples I have seen assume there are distinct actions to take when app is in background mode. In my case (like most?) the app is doing a task--like a timer in main.ts file--and then I want this code to continue to execute when the app goes in background. This may involve communicating between my main.ts file and the custom-app-delegate, but I am trying to figure that out. Is there sample code  about having an action occur in a main ts file, and then having it CONTINUE after background mode?

Comment: There are certain rules Apple wants the developer to follow, so the better you could do is share the code. Write all your logics in a separate file and call it within app and do the same from background execution.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my answer to provide more detail and code. Calling the code from one file and then from another file would not be sufficient, I believe, because calling it AGAIN when the app goes into background mode would cause it to start over. Perhaps there needs to be some process to tell the app where the timer is when it goes into background...but that could get overly complicated I think. Is there a more straightforward solution?

Answer (score 0):

iOS allows you to run code in the background only for certain situations. For instance (but not limited to):

- Background location updates.
- Audio and video playback (PiP in iPad)
- Remote Push Notifications handling
- among others...

If your app does not fit any of the available categories, the best you can do is to [request to iOS more time to run in the background](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/managing_your_app_s_life_cycle/preparing_your_app_to_run_in_the_background/extending_your_app_s_background_execution_time?language=objc) (by default is 10 seconds). This will allow you to run for 3 more minutes. Just keep running the task in an infinite loop and gracefully terminate your app before the granted 180 seconds.

Regarding background fetch, this mechanism allows apps to update its contents in the background. iOS will execute apps that declare background fetch at least once a day, so you, in your delegate can perform an update from the server. This mechanism is not suitable for what you are looking for.